# get JSON from multiple URL using AFNetworking

Tags: cocoa-touch, afnetworking

i need to load more than 50 youtube video on UITableView using AFNetworking.

Do i have to use AFJSONRequestOperation multiple times in viewdidload to download the data ?

Here is what i have tried:

```
NSString *urlAsString = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50";

NSString *urlAsString2 = @"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL7CF5B0AC3B1EB1D5?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=50&start-index=51";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString2];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
```

//Now i have no clue what to do.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    self.videoMetaData = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video"];
    self.allThumbnails = [JSON valueForKeyPath:@"data.items.video.thumbnail"];
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
    // NSLog(@" video Meta Data %@", self.videoMetaData);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
}];
[operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a method and pass the URL into it?

```
-(void)loadVideoFromURL:(NSURL *)url {

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    // setup AFNetworking stuff
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    // call delegate or processing method on success
    [self someDelegateMethod:(NSDictionary *)JSON];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];


    [operation start];

}
```

Comment: How can you do multiple requests doing this?